# How to send error message to the Django generic DeleteView Confirmation Page using JsonResponse

Tags: django, error-handling, django-views, jsonresponse

I am trying to use Django generic DeleteView using the **confirmation page**. The setup is working as intended.

Later the business logic was changed to prevent **deletion** if there are child instances assigned to the object being deleted, using `on_delete=models.PROTECT` in the model.

And the `DeleteView` has been modified to the following:

```
class TerritoryDeleteView(LoginRequiredMixin, DeleteView):
    template_name = ".../trty_delete.html"
    model = Territory
    success_url = reverse_lazy('territories_list')

    # THE FOLLOWING MODIFICATION DONE:
    def delete(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = self.get_object()
        try:
            self.object.delete()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(success_url)
        except ProtectedError:
            error_message = "This object can't be deleted, as an Outlet is already assigned to the Territory..."
            return JsonResponse(error_message, safe=False)
```

The above (modified) view works fine. However, in case it encounters the `ProtectedError`, the `error_message` is shown in a **blank** browser page.

**How could I display the `error_message` in the confirmation page (template) itself?**

Comment: You should use [`render()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/shortcuts/#render) function

Comment: @ArakkalAbu - Thanks. Able to see message now. But, The **object details** (of the object that is being deleted) goes missing from the page now. **For example**, if the object is **Lower Manhattan**, its details are available when the `Delete` option is exercised first (done to facilitate ease of user comprehension). Now when the app encounters the `ProtectedError`, these details go missing altogether. Possibly because on exception, the context is not being transmitted as in normal cases (i.e. in the absence of an **error**). What should I do to keep the context data on the page at all times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, change your ***`delete(...)`*** method to catch the `ProtectedError` error (which you have already done) and then ***pass the error message as context data to the template*** as

```
class TerritoryDeleteView(LoginRequiredMixin, DeleteView):
    template_name = ".../trty_delete.html"
    model = Territory
    success_url = reverse_lazy('territories_list')

    def delete(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            return super().delete(request, *args, **kwargs)
        except ProtectedError:
            self.object = self.get_object()
            context = self.get_context_data(
                object=self.object,
                error="Any error msg"
            )
            return self.render_to_response(context)
```

But, this is not enough, we have to update the *template file* too.

```
<form method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    {% if error %}
        {{ error }}
    {% else %}
        <p>Are you sure you want to delete "{{ object }}"?</p>
        <input type="submit" value="Confirm">
    {% endif %}

</form>
```

**Note:** *This may not fit *exactly* in your case, but, probably this will give you an idea of how to manage the error message nicely.*

Comment: I had already taken care of the conditional display of the **error message**. The part that I was sorely missing was the details of the **object being deleted**. Grateful for your answer. Saved my day!!